# C++ implicit cast in OO

Tags: c++, oop, casting, implicit

my code:

```
class myAbstractClass{

}

class dev1: public myAbstractClass{

}

class dev2: public myAbstractClass{
  public:
  myAbstractClass* temp;
  dev2(myAbstractClass* tmp) { temp=tmp; }
}

int _tmain(){
  dev1 d;
  dev2 derived2(d);
```

How to do this?

error C2040: 'v' : 'dev2' differs in levels of indirection from 'myAbstractClass *'
error C2512: 'dev2' : no appropriate default constructor available

Comment: If that's your actual code, your constructor is private, so the compiler won't let you use it in main().

Comment: Always put the full error text in the question.  (If you're using Visual Studio, that's in the "Output" window, _not_ the "Error" window)

Comment: Along with what Xavier said, you most likely want to inherit your base class publicly.

Comment: A "cast" is something you write in your code; it tells the compiler to do a conversion. It can never be implicit. If the compiler does a conversion without needing a cast, the conversion is an "implicit conversion".

Answer (score 1):

Since the constructor takes a pointer, pass the address-of object!

```
int _tmain()
{ 
      dev1 d; 
      dev2 derived2(&d); // &d
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be convertible to a pointer or reference ofthe base, the base needs to be `public`. By default inheritance is `private` when using the `class` keyword.

Comment: Well, the code you posted isn't the one you compiled (e.g. the posted code lacks semicolons after the class definitions). Also, you want to take the address of `d` (I didn't spot this before).